# Why is the base current of a BJT in PSpice higher than expected?

Tags: transistors, bjt, spice, pspice

I have made a common emitter amplifier in PSpice with an NPN transistor. I have set the Beta value to 200 in the model settings, however, as you can see from the picture, the collector current is not 200 times the base current as would be expected.

When I do the DC analysis, I find that the collector and emitter currents are correct, however the base current I am expecting is 3.98uA, not 7.512uA.

[image: common emitter amplifier bias currents]

These are the model parameters for the Q2N3904 that I'm using:
.model Q2N3904-X1   NPN(
Is=6.734f
Xti=3
Eg=1.11
Vaf=74.03
Bf=200
Ne=1.259
Ise=6.734f
Ikf=66.78m
Xtb=1.5
Br=.7371
Nc=2
Isc=0
Ikr=0
Rc=1
Cjc=3.638p
Mjc=.3085
Vjc=.75
Fc=.5
Cje=4.493p
Mje=.2593
Vje=.75
Tr=239.5n
Tf=301.2p
Itf=.4
Vtf=4
Xtf=2
Rb=10)

Comment: Beta varies with collector current and Vce and some other things like temperature.  How much it varies and how depends on the specifics of your model and its parameters.  Just because you set "beta" to something in the model doesn't mean that the relationship will hold for all operating points.

Comment: We'll need to see the complete model specifications you are using.

Comment: As far as I know the SPICE BJT model does not contain just a simple "beta value".

Comment: Change Ne=1.259 from to Ne = 1.5. You can also delete Ikf or increase it to for example Ikf = 200m